# AutoLayout issue in iOS 7(works perfectly in iOS 8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have designed the app using auto layout. The screens are perfect in iOS 8 (according to the constraints).

Base SDK is iOS 8. The deployment target is from iOS 7.0.

Now when i run the same app in iOS 7. The screens behave strangely. The view will change the layout after view is loaded(this is not the case in iOS 8). Sometime after the views are changed there will be white spaces of 2/3 points at the bottom or the sides.

**Edit**: The white space does not happen every time. Its basically that fact that the layout get updated after the view is loaded is the problem. It looks real bad. Has anyone else faced the same issue?

PS: Never used relative to margin through out the app. All constraints are added using xib.

Note: To "people" who down vote the question. Could you kindly provide the reason in the comments?

Comment: It would be better if you upload some screenshots and code

Comment: Have you added constraints "Relative to Margin" ? If yes that might not work porperly

Comment: I have never used relative to margin through out the app

Comment: @Azat - Well i have used all constraints throughout xib. So no code

Answer (score 0):

If I would have to guess maybe it happens because you use size classes. They are generally working with iOs7 but not with all features and sizes...

edit:
Something like that:

[image]

Comment: is there a way to fix this? Like this constraint change after the view is loaded in iOS 7.

Comment: the app i made uses only the Any Any size class... u can try the following: make your view as big as your super view in the controller and add a constraint on all 4 sides without margin and pin it to the super view...(should have constant with the value 0 on all sides) WIth that it should resize automatically as big as your container depending on the device (works for iOs 7 for me)